# Standard Hyperlink Tag is appending directories

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I can't get this to stick, it should stay the same when clicked but it appends the first two directories to it after it redirects:

```
<a href="~/Main/Content/Company/@Model.CompanyId/RemoveCompany"> remove </a>
```

When I click it, the browser tries to redirect to http://localhost/Main/Content/Companies/68/~/Main/Content/Company/68/RemoveCompany

tried this too

```
<a href="/Main/Content/Company/@Model.CompanyId/RemoveCompany"> remove </a>
```

redirects to http://localhost/Main/Companies/Main/Content/Company/0/RemoveCompany

the route looks like this in our Main Area:

```
context.MapRoute("RemoveCompany", "Main/Content/Company/{id}/RemoveCompany", new { controller = "Company", action = "RemoveCompany", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using a helper?

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Main/Content/Company/" + Model.CompanyId + "/Remove")"> remove </a>
```

or even better: [**Routes**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) - the kind of standard things people use in ASP.NET MVC. Seems like you are trying to hit a controller action belonging to an area or something. So simply setup your routes and get going:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "remove",
    "RemoveCompany", 
    "Company", 
    new {
        area = "main",
        id = Model.CompanyId
    }, 
    null
)
```

given the following Main area registration:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "RemoveCompany", 
    "Main/Content/Company/{id}/RemoveCompany", 
    new { 
        controller = "Company", 
        action = "RemoveCompany", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional 
    });
```

yields:

```
<a href="/Main/Content/Company/123/RemoveCompany">remove</a>
```

Comment: sorry I updated..please see updates in the original post.  Yea I can use a helper but want to get this working with plain html since our UX guy sometimes wants it or has it as such.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, your UX guy might want many things but if you don't use helpers in an ASP.NET MVC application you will struggle enormously. And when you deploy your application in IIS, all the struggling and efforts you did during your development will be invalidated as now you have a virtual directory to think about which changes all your urls. So if you don't use urls all I can wish you is to be prepared to drink lots of coffee and spend sleepless nights :-)

Comment: Yea well try telling that to him, owns and is the web lead so he makes the decisions on the UI side.  I am a consultant so can't force that issue at this point.

Comment: Yea I understand routing...I've used helpers all the time previously.

Comment: Great, then you know what to do.

Comment: I already have a route set up I said, re-read the update in the initial post I said

Comment: tried both ways, it still prepends Main/Company in the begining so I end up with Main/Company/Main/Content/Company/...

Comment: I have updated my answer and the `Html.ActionLink` to match your route. So assuming you have an area called `Main` with a single route definition as the one shown in your question, the ActionLink I suggested in my answer generates `http://localhost:1968/Main/Content/Company/123/RemoveCompany` when I tested.

Comment: don't know what else to do I tried that, it's also not picking up the area name..intellisense that is.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce your problem. I have created a new ASP.NET MVC application, added a new Main area, modified the route definition in `MainAreaRegistration.cs` to match yours and inside the Index view of HomeController used the Html.ActionLink helper shown in my answer which yielded the correct results. So if you expect further help from my side you will have to provide a full scenario allowing me to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I'm gonna have to look more at what's going on here, it's weird.